# Maven exits after trying to run it

Tags: 11.04, command-line, java

I've manually installed sun java 1.6.0_24 and apache maven 3.0.3 into ~/Work on Natty and when I run maven from my terminal it exits.

I've tried various other versions of maven (2.2.1, 2.0.11), previous versions of the jdk (1.6.0_23) without luck.

I've also tried logging in to tty1 and executing mvn from there the result being that my session is lost (ie I'm prompted with the host login).

I am able to duplicate this behaviour with ant so my suspicion is that something is broken in the shell/terminal emulator.

Comment: Please have a look at the logs. It's highly unlikely that the shell or terminal emulator is broken. If maven is exiting unexpectedly, hopefully it'll log that somewhere. It sounds like it's crashing, or maybe Java itself is crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad.  To setup my environment to use java/maven/etc I use a series of scripts in ~/bin, for example ~/bin/env-maven; the heads of which were:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
```

To use the script I source as:

`. ~/bin/env-maven`

Which then tells bash to exit immediately if a non-zero exit code from a pipeline (ie command) is encountered and in my case running mvn without a pom.xml will do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have run more than one version of Maven (e.g., Maven2 & Maven3), then check your environment to make sure you aren't referencing more than one installation.

For example, having M2_HOME will cause mvn 3 not to run (note: I have installed various maven's & java's in /opt):

```
$ type mvn
mvn is /opt/maven3/bin/mvn


$ env | grep 'M.*HOME'
MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven-1.1
M2_HOME=/opt/maven2

$ /opt/maven3/bin/mvn -v
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.  Program will exit.

$ unset M2_HOME

$ /opt/maven3/bin/mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 09:31:09-0800)
Maven home: /opt/maven3
Java version: 1.6.0_23, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_23/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.35-28-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: This was _KILLING_ me. `unset M2_HOME` fixed it. Thank you!